# Missing Return Statement(Java)

Tags: java, recursion

What I'm trying to do is; I have given a sorted array such as; 
1,1,1,2,2,3.
Then I'm given a number such as; 6.
Then I'm trying to find minimum number of array elements that I have to sum to find this number. 
I start from the end of the array to sum elements. 
The answer should be 3 because I used 3 items in the array to sum just like;

3+2+2 (starting from the end) >= 6.

If all the sums still not greater then the given number, I return (-1) to indicate that I can never reach the given number.

My Recursive function is as follows but I'm getting "Missing Return Statement" error. How can I solve thi problem for the given question.

```
    public static int findIt(int[] arr, int index, int min)
{
    if(index >=0)
    {
        int calc=0;
        int counter=0;
        for(int from = arr.length-1 ; from>=index; from--)
        {
            calc += arr[from];
            counter++;
        }
        if(calc>=min)
            return counter;
        else
            findIt(arr, --index, min);
    }
   else
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: What happens after `else
            findIt(arr, --index, min);`?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
findIt(arr, --index, min);
```

Return the value from it like:

```
return findIt(arr, --index, min);
```

Answer (score 0):

The missing return should be after the line `findIt(arr, --index, min);`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `return`:

```
public static int findIt(int[] arr, int index, int min)
{
    if(index >=0)
    {
        int calc=0;
        int counter=0;
        for(int from = arr.length-1 ; from>=index; from--)
        {
            calc += arr[from];
            counter++;
        }
        if(calc>=min)
            return counter;
        else
            findIt(arr, --index, min); // <=== Here
    }
   else
    return -1;
}
```

Putting a `return` in front of `findIt(arr, --index, min);` will return the result of `findIt`.

If a function declares that it returns a value, **all** paths through the code must do so. And separately, for this function to work correctly, you really *want* to return the result of that recursive `findIt` call.